# MariaDB (Mysql) wont turn on SSL

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb

MariaDB always has SSL disabled I have followed everything online with no success. I am hoping someone has seen this issue before thanks!!

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl%';
+---------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name       | Value                  |
+---------------------+------------------------+
| have_openssl        | NO                     |
| have_ssl            | DISABLED               |
| ssl_ca              | /etc/mysql/chain.pem   |
| ssl_capath          |                        |
| ssl_cert            | /etc/mysql/cert.pem    |
| ssl_cipher          | TLSv1.2                |
| ssl_crl             |                        |
| ssl_crlpath         |                        |
| ssl_key             | /etc/mysql/servkey.pem |
| version_ssl_library | YaSSL 2.4.4            |
+---------------------+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your ssl variables of your MariaDB server the server is statically linked against yassl (MariaDB < 10.4).

Since Yassl only supports TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1 the server can't start since the specified Transport Layer Security 1.2 is not supported.

Solutions:

- Use OpenSSL instead of Yassl
- Upgrade to MariaDB to 10.4 or newer
- Omit ssl_cipher in your configuration or downgrade to TLSv1.1